# Numpy loadtxt rounding off numbers

Tags: python, numpy

I'm using numpy loadtxt function to read in a large set of data. The data appears to be rounded off. for example: The number in the text file is -3.79000000000005E+01 but numpy reads the number in as -37.9. I've set the dypte to np.float64 in the loadtxt call. Is there anyway to keep the precision of the original data file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`loadtxt` is not rounding the number. What you are seeing is the way NumPy chooses to *print* the array:

```
In [80]: import numpy as np

In [81]: x = np.loadtxt('test.dat', dtype = np.float64)

In [82]: print(x)
-37.9
```

The actual value is the np.float64 closest to the value inputted.

```
In [83]: x
Out[83]: array(-37.9000000000005)
```

---

Or, in the more likely instance that you have a higher dimensional array,

```
In [2]: x = np.loadtxt('test.dat', dtype = np.float64)
```

If the `repr` of `x` looks truncated:

```
In [3]: x
Out[3]: array([-37.9, -37.9])
```

you can use `np.set_printoptions` to get higher precision:

```
In [4]: np.get_printoptions()
Out[4]: 
{'edgeitems': 3,
 'infstr': 'inf',
 'linewidth': 75,
 'nanstr': 'nan',
 'precision': 8,
 'suppress': False,
 'threshold': 1000}

In [5]: np.set_printoptions(precision = 17)

In [6]: x
Out[6]: array([-37.90000000000050306, -37.90000000000050306])
```

(Thanks to @mgilson for pointing this out.)

Comment: It might also be instructive to mention [`np.set_printoptions`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html)

Comment: Excellent. That solved the mystery. Changing the np.set_printoptions let the full numbers print.