# How to increase precision for Numpy loadtxt?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to read the data from a text file, and I am using NumPy.loadtxt(). My numbers are tiny, and the computations are very sensitive if the numbers are rounded. If one of the numbers that I read from the file is `-2.74950545281171798706054687500e-02`, it is actually read as `-2.749505452811718e-02`. I tried the approach given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14885660/numpy-loadtxt-rounding-off-numbers), but it didn't work. How can I read the entire number without losing the precision?

Comment: If you need *that* much precision, standard floating point data types won't help you. You *already* lost precision before you even wrote this text file - `-2.74950545281171798706054687500e-02` is a standard 64-bit float printed to more digits of precision than it actually has.

Comment: At least, how can I get the number as it is `-2.74950545281171798706054687500e-02` after reading?

Comment: You *did* get exactly that number. NumPy just doesn't show you the excess digits by default, because they're meaningless for most purposes and because seeing 0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625 when you type 0.1 would be more confusing than helpful.

Comment: (Note that you only got exactly the number in the file because the text file already has precision loss. If you actually had 30 decimal digits worth of true precision in your text file, you would not be able to represent those numbers in a standard 64-bit floating point number.)

Comment: You probably don't need 30 decimal digits of precision, anyway. It's almost impossible to take a physical measurement accurate to 30 digits (aside from discrete quantities like "2 apples").

Comment: If I use the variable directly without saving and reading from the text file, I get a different result than the computations done on the variable read from the text file. And there is a significant deviation on the outcome. Therefore, I guess that there is a number precision problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying several approaches, I found that, e.g., if the data type of the number being saved is float64, then we should read it as float64 data. It retrieves the original number without precision loss. Following is the code snippet:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.array([-2.74950545281171798706054687500e-06,   3.14752431798706054687500e-07])
print(data.dtype) #float64
np.savetxt('expectation_data.txt', data) 

# Now read the data
read_data = np.loadtxt('expectation_data.txt', dtype = np.float64)

# Check if one of the saved and read data are the same
if read_data[0] == data[0]:
    print('Yes')
else:
    print('No')
```

As commented by `@user2357112 supports Monica`, Numpy doesn't save and show excess digits.